# jquery hover triggering on element under absolute element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have the jQuery hover event (or mouseenter or mouseover events) trigger on an element that is positioned under a fixed or absolutely positioned div that covers the triggering element?  Hopefully this makes sense.  Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
This is the solution I came up with. Are there any more efficient ways of doing what this code accomplishes?  http://jsfiddle.net/GQugb/5/  Only problem with it is if the user goes really fast over the boxes, eventually they will all get stuck yellow. Any suggestions?

Comment: nope. You can use jQuery to trigger the hover event when the mouse hovers over you absolutely positioned element. Post some html, css and jquery code and maybe we can find a solution for you.

Comment: I don't have any code really worth showing at the moment. What I am trying to achieve is a hover/highlight function to let users know they are over a certain element. When hovering over the element, an opaque div will be positioned over the element to lighten it without affecting the style of that element (background, border, etc.). This is fine; however when you highlight over a nested element, the event will not trigger because it is over the absolutely positioned div. I'm not really looking for code, just a concept that may work

Comment: have you looked into this? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Comment: I have looked at that method, its just not what I am looking for. I have considered checking the mouse position with each element left, width, top, and height but I figured it would be extremely slow

Comment: what about this? http://jsfiddle.net/dmN6D/ you could set the divs opacity and position it over what you want to highlight...

Comment: @Tony not perfect but an idea. Notice there are 2 `div`'s. Anyway, good luck. http://jsfiddle.net/dmN6D/6/

Comment: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/SRqV7/4/  [link] I would like the back div to not be highlighted when the front div is being hovered

Comment: @Tony not perfect by any means but this is a start. The problem is that the parent hover function always gets fired. Depending on how the mouse enters the div, it works and it kinda doesn't work. I hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/SRqV7/12/

Answer (score 0):

before the edit i would have said "try css: .outer{ pointer-events:none;}",

after the edit, i'd suggest a lock variable for each hover function:

```
var lock = false;
function hover(){
   if(lock) return;
   lock=true;

   //do stuff

   setTimeout(function(){lock=false;},1000); //1 second delay
}
```